# Newton Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-3}^5 f(x)\,dx$$
for
$$  f(x) =\begin{cases}
1/x^2,  & \text{if }x \neq 0 \\
-10^{17}, & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}
$$

I tried with Newton Leibniz formula, is this correct ?

$\int_{-3}^0 f(x)dx$  + $\int_{0}^5 f(x)dx$ =

$1/x^2 |_{-3}^{0} $ $ + $ $1/x^2 |_0^5$=

$3/(-3)^2+10^{17}+(-10^{17})-3/5^2)$= $16/75$

I know I made a mistake, but I dont know what, could someone please correct me and help me.

Comment: The Newton-Leibniz formula only applies to continuous functions.

Comment: It has no (Riemann) integral in any region around $0$.

Comment: Wait, but how do I solve this then ?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "solve this", and are you sure there is a solution in the sense you mean?

Comment: Sadly I don't know, this question was on the test last year. I am trying to figure it out how to solve it. I think that there should be a solution to this problem. It only states "Calculate the integral" on the test, so i suppose there is a solution or maybe it is a trick question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $-10^{17}$ is a red herring: the value of a function at a single point has no effect on the integral.  On the other hand, this does signal that something funny is likely to be happening as $x \to 0$, and indeed it does: the integrand goes to 
$\infty$ there.  Since the integrand is unbounded, this is not an ordinary Riemann integral, but rather an improper integral.  For that, you want to take a limit:

$$ \int_{-3}^5 f(x)\; dx = \lim_{a \to 0-} \int_{-3}^a f(x)\; dx + \lim_{b \to 0+} \int_b^5 f(x)\; dx $$
However, (if you use a correct antiderivative) you'll find that both of these limits are $+\infty$.  So the conclusion is that the improper integral does not exist (or is $+\infty$, depending on your point of view).

Answer (score 2):

$\frac1{x^2}$ is not the integral of $\frac1{x^2}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well it is right, in this case a "you have a mistake" answer is really okay.